# How to execute for loop while RPM creation inside %build, %install and %files section?

Tags: linux, rpm, rpmbuild

I am creating an RPM. But the contents of the RPM needs to be installed at different places. Inside `%build`, I am supposed to run a loop to pick up all the locations from a XML file. Here is my snippet:

```
%build
for j in ${!files[*]}
do
 mkdir -p ${fileLocations[j]}
done

%install
for i in ${!files[*]}
do
 cp -rfR $SOURCE/${fileNames[i]} ${fileLocations[i]}
done
```

The variable looping character is set to 1 it seems. How to achive this?

Comment: It's simply `bash`. That doesn't look like standard bash syntax.

Comment: But its working fine from another shell script. Are the issues due to the %build tag?

Answer (score 0):

It seems `files` is a bash variable that must be re-initialized in each different stage (`%build`, `%install`, etc.). Each of these actually become temporary scripts that are executed.

For the `%files` stanza, you are no longer in a shell, but you can have them written to a file and read in with the `-f` option. That might be the better way to get them into the other stanzas as well anyway.

Comment: I tried that as well with the following:                                                      %build
files=($(grep -oP '(?<=file>)[^<]+' "PatchContent/RPMSpec.xml"))
locations=($(grep -oP '(?<=outputDirectory>)[^<]+' "PatchContent/RPMSpec.xml"))                                                                    for i in ${files[*]}
do
echo "Value of I is " ${i}
echo ${files[$i]}
echo ${locations[$i]}
# fileLocations[i]="${locations[$i]}"
 echo "Inside makeDirectory" ${locations[$i]}/${files[$i]}
 #mkdir -p ${locations[$i]}/${files[$i]}
done